# Using enumerate environment within a theorem environment

Tags: theorems, enumerate

I am writing a math article, and when I am in a `theorem` environment and I try to use the enumerate environment, everything is italicized where, out of the `theorem` environment, it wouldn't be.

Is there a way to get my item labels to look like (I), (II), etc., instead of the italicized forms of these item labels that I am currently getting?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format :) In particular, it would be great to see a small, complete MWE that demonstrates the problem :) Welcome!

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165489/15925

Comment: Greetings to everyone!  I do not know how it is conventional to proceed now that it has been made clear that this question is a duplicate question.  Referring to the notice below, there is nothing to edit (for, it is still my exact question) and it is not different from the other similar questions.  But, in truth, Bernard's answer below is exactly what I wanted, and is incredibly simple compared to the answer suggested above.  I think other people with this same question might find his answer useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

in the preamble, then

```
\begin{enumerate}[\upshape(i)]
\item ...
```

You also may set it in the preamble:

```
\setlist{enumerate}{label=\upshape(\roman*)}
```

[image]