# Using a theorem-based environment inside a list

Tags: lists, theorems, enumerate

When I include a theorem-based environment right after the start of a list item, a linebreak is inserted that looks a little funny.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\begin{document}
Problem:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of problem
    \item Second part of problem
\end{enumerate}

Solution:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of solution
    \item
    \begin{claim}
        Result X holds
    \end{claim}
    By Result X, the second part follows.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The linebreak occurs after Item 2 of the solution, since theorem environments always start with a linebreak. Is there an alternative to a theorem environment that I should be using? I am looking for a solution that is as canonical as possible, and doesn't require tweaking lots of settings manually.

**EDIT:** While updating my code snippet to make it a MWE, I realized that omitting the `\usepackage{amsthm}` fixes the problem. However, in my actual LaTeX document I would prefer to keep using amsthm.

Comment: See [enumerating-inside-a-proposition-and-inside-a-proof](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165489/enumerating-inside-a-proposition-and-inside-a-proof)

Comment: That post is about an enum inside a theorem; my post is about a theorem inside an enum. How does it apply?

Comment: Sorry, I read your title backwards. One option would be to define your `claim` environment using the `enumitem` package -- so something like `\newlist{claim}{description}{1}`. Then you could set its parameters using `\setlist`. Be good if you could add a MWE.

Comment: you don't say what packages you're using, but most theorem packages expect that you'll be on the "outer" level when inputting a theorem object.  unless you expect to cross-reference this claim later, i'd suggest simply emulating the style manually, or providing a "simple" definition for the situation.  not a great approach, but trying to overcome a rather complicated theorem environment definition is going to be at least a headache, and may well cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: See the updated question; I am using amsthm, which introduces the extra line break.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is there a way I can disable the linebreak before a theorem, or is this a complicated procedure?

Comment: @pre-kidney -- you seem to have found a workaround using `ntheorem`.  i'm not familiar with the adjustments in that package, so if it does what you need, use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround that seems to work. Simply replace `\usepackage{amsthm}` with `\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}`. This avoids the extra linebreak.

Comment: I didn'tknow that one! Anyway, I always use `ntheorem`  for its automatic placement of end-of-proof symbol, even when the proof ends with displayed equations.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Andrew, it's much simpler to define a claim environment as a special `description` environment, with the `enumitem` package. Here is a way to go.

Actually I also define a `claims` environment, for a series of such ‘claims’. It has a counter, and so can be referenced intelligently through the `cleveref` package. I reset this counter per section, but, supposing your problems or solutions are numbered environments (say theorem-like), you can easily reset `claimno` per problem or solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newenvironment{claim}{%
\def\claim{\item[\mdseries\em Claim: ]}%
\begin{description}[wide]}%
{\end{description}}

\newenvironment{claims}{%
\newcounter{claimno}[section]\def\claim{\refstepcounter{claimno}\item[\mdseries\em Claim \theclaimno: ]}%
\begin{description}[wide]}%
{\end{description}}
\crefname{claimno}{claim}{claims}
\Crefname{claimno}{Claim}{Claims}

\begin{document}
Problem:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of problem\label{part2}
    \item Second part of problem
\end{enumerate}
Solution:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of solution
    \item \begin{claims}
     \claim\label{cl1}   Result X holds.  Some comments some comments some comments some comments some comments some comments some comments some comments some comments
     \claim  \mbox{}\\ Result Y holds.
\end{claims}
    By \cref{cl1}, the second part follows.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is some investigative work, revealed via the addition of `\showoutput` to your preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
Problem:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of problem
    \item Second part of problem
\end{enumerate}

Solution:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of solution
    \item 
    \begin{claim}
        Result X holds
    \end{claim}
    By Result X, the second part follows.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The `.log` includes the following piece of information:

```
...\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
...\glue -8.0 plus -2.0 minus -4.0
...\glue 4.0 minus 3.0
...\glue(\parskip) 4.0 plus 2.0 minus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
...\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x319.99997, glue set 209.07147fil, shifted 25.00003
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 C
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 l
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 a
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 i
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 m
....\kern 0.0
....\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91666 minus 1.27777
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 1
....\kern 0.0
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
```

The above shows the construction of **Claim 1.**. Immediately preceding it some `glue` is set. In particular `4.0 minus 3.0`, `\parskip` and `\baselineskip`. Added together you can reverse the vertical skip:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}
Problem:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of problem
    \item Second part of problem
\end{enumerate}

Solution:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First part of solution
    \item \leavevmode\par\vspace*{\dimexpr-4pt-\parskip-\baselineskip}%
    \begin{claim}
        Result X holds
    \end{claim}
    By Result X, the second part follows.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```