# Theorem inside an enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate, theorems

While I have come across a number of questions concerning the formatting of lists within a theorem environment, I could not find any material regarding the converse.

Suppose I would like to have an enumerated list of propositions and corresponding proofs (for instance, in preparing homework solutions for a number of proof questions).

The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{proposition}
            State some proposition.
        \end{proposition}

        \begin{proof}
            Prove the proposition elegantly.
        \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

produces an numbered item for which the first line is blank, i.e.,

```
1.

   Proposition. Some formal proposition.

   Proof. Prove the proposition elegantly. (Box)
```

Is it possible at all to remove the blank first line and obtain the following?

```
1. Proposition. Some formal proposition.

   Proof. Prove the proposition elegantly. (Box)
```

Comment: `amsthm` has the option to `\swapnumbers`.  if you're not referring to theorems numbered elsewhere, that might suffice.

Comment: However, to achieve the desired formatting would require further customization of the proposition numbering (using a simple vanilla `\swapnumbers` changes the output to `1 Proposition.`, whereas I wish to have `1. Proposition`), and neither the body of the proposition nor the proof will be indented in line with the numbering, unlike in a proper list.

Answer (score 2):

This is the OP again. In case anyone else might be interested now or in future, I present a workable solution I eventually came up with (although I have no idea whether it could  be considered "best practice") that combines answers to questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193169/using-a-theorem-based-environment-inside-a-list) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296434/with-ntheorem-thmmarks-and-no-amsthm-defining-the-proof-environment-right).

I replace the amsthm package `\usepackage{amsthm}` with the more flexible ntheorem `\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}` to avoid the extra line break, and then redefine a `proof` environment within `ntheorem`, as it does not include one by default.

Thus, the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremseparator{.\;}

\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}

\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem*{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{proposition}
            State some proposition.
        \end{proposition}

        \begin{proof}
            Prove the proposition elegantly.
        \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

outputs my desired result.

Comment: you can accept own answer :-)